# Android Checkbox position in Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

After hours of searching I'm unable to quite figure this out.

I'm trying to save the checkbox state using shared preferences. As far as I know it's saving the state. However, the position is all off and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The btnToggle state works fine but the checkBox state which I'm not storing in the database is not and I don't want to have to use the database to store the state of that checkBox. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class AlarmListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<AlarmModel> mAlarms;
Alarms displayAlarm = new Alarms();
ViewHolder viewHolder;
private CheckBox checkBox ;

public AlarmListAdapter(Context context, List<AlarmModel> alarms) {
    mContext = context;
    mAlarms = alarms;

}

public void setAlarms(List<AlarmModel> alarms) {
    mAlarms = alarms;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mAlarms != null) {
        return mAlarms.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (mAlarms != null) {
        return mAlarms.get(position);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (mAlarms != null) {
        return mAlarms.get(position).id;
    }
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder
{

    RelativeLayout share;
    RelativeLayout fav;
    RelativeLayout info;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    Switch btnToggle;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    final AlarmModel model = (AlarmModel) getItem(position);


    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.visible_toggle);

        viewHolder.btnToggle = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_toggle);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


    }
    else{

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.checkBox.getTag(position);
        viewHolder.btnToggle.getTag(position);


    }




    viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(Long.valueOf(model.id)); // This line is important.

    viewHolder.btnToggle.setTag(Long.valueOf(model.id));

    TextView txtTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_time);
    txtTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", model.timeHour, model.timeMinute));

    TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_name);
    txtName.setText(model.name);

    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_sunday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SUNDAY));
    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_monday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.MONDAY));
    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_tuesday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.TUESDAY));
    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_wednesday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.WEDNESDAY));
    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_thursday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.THURSDAY));
    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_friday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.FRDIAY));
    updateTextColor((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_saturday), model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SATURDAY));




    viewHolder.btnToggle.setChecked(model.isEnabled);
    viewHolder.btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            ((AlarmSettings) mContext).setAlarmEnabled(((Long) buttonView.getTag()).longValue(), isChecked);
        }
    });



    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(getFromSP("visbox"));
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isVisible){

            viewHolder.checkBox.getTag(position);


            try {
                saveInSp("visbox", isVisible);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(isVisible) {

             // Do stuff here



            }
            else {





            }

        }


    });




    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((AlarmSettings) mContext).startAlarmDetailsActivity(((Long) view.getTag()).longValue());
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            ((AlarmSettings) mContext).deleteAlarm((Long) view.getTag());
            return true;
        }
    });




    return convertView;
}





private void updateTextColor(TextView view, boolean isOn) {
    if (isOn) {
        view.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
    } else {
        view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}



private boolean getFromSP(String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("epimelis.com.lyre", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean val = preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    System.out.println("getting key: "+ key + " with value: " + val);
    return val;
}
private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value) throws Exception {
    //if(!value) throw new Exception("Die Die Die");ooo
    System.out.println("Saving key: " + key + " with value: " + value);
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("epimelis.com.lyre", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Try to add one more flag "isChecked" in your AlarmModel class with default value false and use below code.

```
public class AlarmListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<AlarmModel> mAlarms;
    Alarms displayAlarm = new Alarms();

    public AlarmListAdapter(Context context, List<AlarmModel> alarms) {
        mContext = context;
        mAlarms = alarms;
    }

    public void setAlarms(List<AlarmModel> alarms) {
        mAlarms = alarms;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAlarms.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mAlarms.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mAlarms.get(position).id;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        Switch btnToggle;
        TextView txtTime;
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtSunday;
        TextView txtMonday;
        TextView txtTuesday;
        TextView txtWednesday;
        TextView txtThursday;
        TextView txtFriday;
        TextView txtSaturday;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);
            viewHolder.btnToggle = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_toggle);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.visible_toggle);
            viewHolder.txtTime = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_time);
            viewHolder.txtName = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_name);
            viewHolder.txtSunday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_sunday);
            viewHolder.txtMonday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_monday);
            viewHolder.txtTuesday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_tuesday);
            viewHolder.txtWednesday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_wednesday);
            viewHolder.txtThursday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_thursday);
            viewHolder.txtFriday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_friday);
            viewHolder.txtSaturday = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_saturday);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.txtTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", mAlarms.get(position).timeHour, mAlarms.get(position).timeMinute));
        viewHolder.txtName.setText(mAlarms.get(position).name);

        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SUNDAY));
        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.MONDAY));
        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.TUESDAY));
        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.WEDNESDAY));
        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.THURSDAY));
        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.FRDIAY));
        updateTextColor(viewHolder.txtMonday, mAlarms.get(position).getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SATURDAY));

        viewHolder.btnToggle.setChecked(mAlarms.get(position).isEnabled);
        viewHolder.btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                ((AlarmSettings) mContext).setAlarmEnabled((position), isChecked);
                mAlarms.get(position).isEnabled = isChecked;
            }
        });

        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mAlarms.get(position).isChecked);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isVisible){
                mAlarms.get(position).isChecked = isVisible;
                if(isVisible) {
                    // Do visible stuff here
                }
                else {
                    // Do invisible or gone stuff here

                }

            }


        });

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((AlarmSettings) mContext).startAlarmDetailsActivity(position);
            }
        });

        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                ((AlarmSettings) mContext).deleteAlarm(position);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private void updateTextColor(TextView view, boolean isOn) {
        if (isOn) {
            view.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
        } else {
            view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
```